# What is the significance of "eventInstanceId" that is provided in response of "Fires the entry event that initiates the journey."

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What is the significance of "eventInstanceId" that is provided in response of "Fires the entry event that initiates the journey."
Is there any possible way to find the status of the records entered into the journey in future with the help of "eventInstanceId".

Below is the API reference I am refering to:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "ContactKey": "CK-001",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"Event-123",
    "Data": {
        "Email":"testemail@gmail.com",
        "Name":"John Smith" }
}

HTTP/1.1 201
{
     "eventInstanceId": "########-####-####-####-############"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The eventInstanceId is the ID unique to the particular request injecting the contact into the journey. This will be used throughout the journey internally to SFMC to track the contact. It can be exposed within Custom Journey Builder activities for tracking purposes or with data binding for various scenarios.

Comment: When you say "used throughout the journey internally" do you mean it has no other references to exposed data points like other REST API endpoints or system data views?